# Angular2 and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to create an Angular2 project with a REST service, using NodeJs. Although I found some tutorials/sample codes doing this kind of applications, the organization of the code/project is different form each other. I'm trying to figure out what's the best way so far to do that.

Basically,

- what is the best approach to creating Angular2 project with NodeJs back end?
- what should be the folder structure?
- where to put the Angular code(with TypeScript)?
- how to use Bower/Gulp?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- A sample of Angular2 + NodeJS and a few other things: http://thejackalofjavascript.com/developing-a-mean-app-with-angular-2-0/
- You can use Angular-Cli to create the initial project structure: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli
- Gulp tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/automate-your-tasks-easily-with-gulp-js
- I do not recommend using bower. Use npm instead, as it is more stable, and has more support from the tools.